# Why are there no LIV Golf golfers in US Open featured groups?

Tags: golf, media

The following list are featured golfers at the US Open:

- Justin Thomas
- Tony Finau
- Victor Hovland
- Brooks Koepka
- Cameron Smith
- Scottie Scheffler
- Rory McIlroy
- Hideki Matsuyama
- Xander Schauffele
- Adam Scott
- Jordan Spieth
- Max Homa

One thing in common about this list is that it does not include a LIV Golf golfer (such as Phil Mickelson or Dustin Johnson). Is the US Open deliberately keeping coverage away from LIV Golf golfers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LIV players are banned from PGA tour and its events. The US Open is not run by the PGA, so the organizers let LIV players to still play this year. But they may ban them in the coming years.

[Here's an article](https://www.sportingnews.com/us/golf/news/usga-liv-golf-players-suspended-pga-tour-us-open/rvmtqlwkt6jzqmwdztnqt9ba) that talks about this in more details. At the end of the day, tournaments like The Masters that are invitational only, or those like the US Open that have a non PGA governing body (in this case USGA) can chose who they let to play. They're allowed to play for now, but don't expect them to be treated the same during broadcasting.